# Available Year-Months Between

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, view

I have a listing of products each product has a [created date] and an [end date](this is null if it has not ended). I am trying to come up with a way to view the number of available products for each 'YYYY-MM'. I need this to go back in time as well as look at current time periods. Any thouhts?

Desired Results:

[image]

Raw Data:

[image]

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using; (2) Provide sample data; (3) Provide desired results; (4) Your attempt to solve the problem is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
-- parameters
declare 
   @sy int = 2014,
   @sm int = 5,
   @nm int = 30;

with months as (
    -- use tally table instead, if present
    select top(@nm) n = @sy*12 + @sm  - 1  + row_number() over (order by (select null))
    from sys.all_objects
)
select year=(m.n-1)/12, month=(m.n-1)%12 + 1, cnt = count(*) 
from (
     -- sample data
     values (1, cast ('20160105' as date), cast(null as date))
           ,(2, cast ('20151115' as date), cast('20160302' as date))
    ) t (id, startDate, endDate)
join months m ON m.n between year(startDate)*12 + month(startDate) 
            and coalesce (year(endDate)*12 + month(endDate), 9999999) 
group by m.n
order by m.n;
```

If you need to show months with no data too, reverse the join order

```
-- parameters
declare 
   @sy int = 2014,
   @sm int = 5,
   @nm int = 30;

with months as (
    -- use tally table instead, if present
    select top(@nm) n = @sy*12 + @sm  - 1  + row_number() over (order by (select null))
    from sys.all_objects
)
select year=(m.n-1)/12, month=(m.n-1)%12 + 1, cnt = count(t.id) 
from  months m
left join (
     -- sample data kindly provided by Slava Murygin
 values 
   (1,cast('2016-05-05' as date),cast('2016-07-23' as date)),
   (2,'2015-04-05',Null),
   (3,'2016-05-05',Null),
   (4,'2016-01-01',Null),
   (5,'2015-02-12','2016-07-23'),
   (6,'2016-03-05',Null),
   (7,'2013-04-15','2016-05-05'),
   (8,'2016-04-10',Null),
   (9,'2015-09-09',Null),
   (10,'2012-08-08','2016-07-23'),
   (11,'2016-06-06',Null),
   (12,'2016-07-07',Null)
    ) t (id, startDate, endDate)
    on m.n between year(startDate)*12 + month(startDate) 
            and coalesce (year(endDate)*12 + month(endDate), 9999999) 
group by m.n
order by m.n;
```

Result

```
year    month   cnt
2014    5   2
2014    6   2
2014    7   2
2014    8   2
2014    9   2
2014    10  2
2014    11  2
2014    12  2
2015    1   2
2015    2   3
2015    3   3
2015    4   4
2015    5   4
2015    6   4
2015    7   4
2015    8   4
2015    9   5
2015    10  5
2015    11  5
2015    12  5
2016    1   6
2016    2   6
2016    3   7
2016    4   8
2016    5   10
2016    6   10
2016    7   11
2016    8   8
2016    9   8
2016    10  8
```

Comment: This appears to work in the example, what do i need to change in the sample data section to connect it to my table that has id, startdate, and enddate?

Comment: Replace `(
     -- sample data
     values (1, cast ('20160105' as date), cast(null as date))
           ,(2, cast ('20151115' as date), cast('20160302' as date))
    ) t (id, startDate, endDate)` with your table name

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt work my counts are returning number way too low.  ie 2016 8 count is 4 when in reality it is actually 600.

Comment: See updated answer with more data and the results. I see nothing  wrong.

Comment: Is it possible the difference is for sample data you are loading Null and in the data set i have since it is a date null is actuall 1900-01-01?

Comment: Do you mean your real data set uses endDate=1900-01-01  to designate open interval?

Comment: then `and coalesce (nullif(year(endDate)*12 + month(endDate),1900*12+1), 9999999)` to account for both null and special value

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to return ALL active periods:

```
SELECT * INTO #MyTable FROM (VALUES
(1,'2016-05-05','2016-07-23'),
(2,'2015-04-05',Null),
(3,'2016-05-05',Null),
(4,'2016-01-01',Null),
(5,'2015-02-12','2016-07-23'),
(6,'2016-03-05',Null),
(7,'2013-04-15','2016-05-05'),
(8,'2016-04-10',Null),
(9,'2015-09-09',Null),
(10,'2012-08-08','2016-07-23'),
(11,'2016-06-06',Null),
(12,'2016-07-07',Null)
) as x (ID, Created,[End])
GO
;WITH MinMax as ( 
    SELECT 
        DATEDIFF(month,MIN(Created),MAX(Created))+1 as MCNT, 
        DATEDIFF(day,MIN(Created),MAX(Created))+1 as DCNT, 
        DATEADD(day,1-day(MIN(Created)),MIN(Created)) as MBegin,
        DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,MAX(Created))+1,0)) as MEnd
    FROM #MyTable
), Periods1 as (
    SELECT TOP (SELECT MCNT FROM MinMax) 
        DATEADD(Month,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1,MBegin)  as MBegin,
        DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,DATEADD(Month,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1,MBegin))+1,0)) as MEnd
    FROM sys.messages CROSS JOIN MinMax
), Periods2 as (
    SELECT ID, DATEADD(Day,rn,Created) as CDay, [End]
    FROM #MyTable
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP (SELECT DCNT FROM MinMax) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 as rn 
        FROM sys.messages) as r
    WHERE DATEADD(Day,rn,Created) < (SELECT MEnd FROM MinMax) and
        ([End] is Null or DATEADD(Day,rn,Created) <= [End])
), Available as (
    SELECT MBegin, ID FROM Periods1 as p1
    INNER JOIN Periods2 as p2 ON p2.CDay between p1. MBegin and MEnd
    GROUP BY MBegin, ID
)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),MBegin,121) as 'Year-Month'
    , COUNT(*) as 'Products Active'
FROM Available
GROUP BY MBegin
ORDER BY MBegin Desc;
GO
```

Comment: This will show me what is currently active but what if i want to retroactively look back 3 years. This also doesnt cumulate the counts if it is still active, ie if it was created in june and is still active the count should be added to all months after that until it is ended.

Comment: @user5963760, update the question to show input parameters, Strat-Year-Month and Number-of-Months for example.

Comment: @user5963760 Please specify what to do with 'partial' month. Like: is '5/15/2016' available in May?

Comment: If it is a partial month then it is considered available in that month yes.

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 6
'EOMONTH' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 11
'EOMONTH' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: EOMONTH: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx  If you are on earlier version you can use `SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@d)+1,0))` instead. Will update the script.